# Element 'price' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only

Tags: xml, validation, web, schema

I am trying to validate my XML file against my XML Schema, however I am being given the following two errors for each item in my XML file:

cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'price' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.

cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'price' is not complete. One of '{"":one_and_half_litre}' is expected.

Here is a sample of the XML file:

```
<soft_drinks>
    <drink>
        <name>Coca Cola</name>
        <price>â¬1.60</price>
    </drink>
    <drink>
        <name>Coca Cola Zero</name>
        <price>â¬1.60</price>
    </drink>
    <drink>
        <name>Coca Cola Diet</name>
        <price>â¬1.60</price>
    </drink>
    <drink>
        <name>Sprite</name>
        <price>â¬1.60</price>
    </drink>
    <drink>
        <name>Sprite Zero</name>
        <price>â¬1.60</price>
    </drink>
    <drink>
        <name>Fanta Orange</name>
        <price>â¬1.60</price>
    </drink>
    <drink>
        <name>Fanta Lemon</name>
        <price>â¬1.60</price>
    </drink>
</soft_drinks>
```

Below is the part of the XML Schema:

```
<xs:element name="soft_drinks">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="drink" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                                <xs:element name="price">
                                </xs:element>
                            </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
```

Thanks if you can help!! :)

Comment: Your schema wants nodes for your drink sizes below your <price> nodes. Different sizes may have different prices.

Comment: What happens if you specify `type="xs:string"` on `price` too?

Comment: And what is your question? Help with what? The error messages look correct in my eyes, what do you need help with? Translating them?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to add:

`type="xs:string"`

to the price element.

Hope it helps